# traefik / ProxyPass: using stripprefix, I get a 404 for sub queries

Tags: docker, configuration, middleware, traefik

I try to configure my registry service to intercep host+path `https://my-dns.org/registry` and redirect to the service `http://registry-ui`

here is configured my compose :

```
...

  registry-ui:
    image: joxit/docker-registry-ui:latest
    container_name: registry-ui
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - REGISTRY_TITLE=My registry
      - NGINX_PROXY_PASS_URL=http://registry:5000
      - SINGLE_REGISTRY=true
      - DELETE_IMAGES=true
    depends_on:
      - registry
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.registry-ui.entrypoints=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.registry-ui.rule=Host(`my-dns.org`) && PathPrefix(`/registry`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.registry-ui.middlewares=test-stripprefix"
      - "traefik.http.routers.registry-ui.tls.certresolver=myresolver"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.test-stripprefix.stripprefix.prefixes=/registry"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.test-stripprefix.stripprefix.forceSlash=false"
      - "traefik.http.services.registry-ui.loadbalancer.server.port=80"
...
```

As a result, the index page works fine, but css, js and favicon are lost because the requests look like :

- `https://my-dns.org/docker-registry-ui.css` instead of
- `https://my-dns.org/registry/docker-registry-ui.css`

Any idea on how to fix that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will only work as long as the app you are trying to start does **NOT** set a custom html `<base>` to something hardcoded like root `/`.

If this is not the case you might be in luck!

Your links to sub resources are probably defined relative something like this.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="docker-registry-ui.css" />
```

So when you enter into the browser `https://my-dns.org/registry` your page opens but all links and subsequently css, js is completely broken because the base directory the relative links are based on is still the directory `https://my-dns.org/` because you did not enter a subdirectory. The `/registry` is handled like it is a file and is ignored for relative links.

- URL:  `https://my-dns.org/registry`
- Base: `https://my-dns.org/`
- Relative Link: `docker-registry-ui.css`
- Result: `https://my-dns.org/docker-registry-ui.css` ⇒ HTTP 404 not found

For your path prefix to work you need to enter a trailing slash `/` to access your service. Then the relative links will work as expected.

- URL:  `https://my-dns.org/registry/`
- Base: `https://my-dns.org/registry/`
- Relative Link: `docker-registry-ui.css`
- Result: `https://my-dns.org/registry/docker-registry-ui.css` ⇒ Link working as expected

Try to access your service with `https://my-dns.org/registry/` (trailing slash) for your links to work as expected.

If you really must use the link without the trailing slash `/` to work, you need a path rewrite step to add the trailing slash or alternatively a redirection from `https://my-dns.org/registry` to `https://my-dns.org/registry/`.

Adjust your configuration to add add the trailing slash:

```yaml
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.registry-ui.entrypoints=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.registry-ui.rule=Host(`my-dns.org`) && PathPrefix(`/registry/`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.registry-ui.middlewares=test-stripprefix"
      - "traefik.http.routers.registry-ui.tls.certresolver=myresolver"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.test-stripprefix.stripprefix.prefixes=/registry/"
      - "traefik.http.services.registry-ui.loadbalancer.server.port=80"
```

Answer (score 0):

I spent hours searching for a solution to the problem of redirects and preserving URL prefixes in Traefik. I finally found a solution based on [this discussion](https://github.com/AdguardTeam/AdGuardHome/issues/1300#issuecomment-1731908998). The key was to use the [Rewrite Header plugin](https://plugins.traefik.io/plugins/628c9eb5108ecc83915d7758/rewrite-header) for Traefik.

The issue I encountered was related to maintaining a URL prefix (e.g., `/myapp`) during redirects initiated by a web application. By default, Traefik does not modify the `Location` header in `HTTP` redirect responses, leading to the loss of the prefix during redirection.

My configs that works for me.

**traefik.yml** (adding the plugin)

```
experimental:
 plugins:
  traefik-plugin-rewrite-headers:
   moduleName: "github.com/XciD/traefik-plugin-rewrite-headers"
   version: "v0.0.4"
```

**traefik-dynamic.yml** (configuring the service)

```
routers:
adguard:
  rule: "Host(`v.my-domain.com`) && PathPrefix(`/agh`)"
  service: "adguard-service"
  entryPoints:
    - "websecure"
  middlewares:
    - "strip-adguard-prefix"
    - "adjust-adguard-redirect"
  tls:
    certResolver: "letsEncrypt"
services:
 adguard-service:
  loadBalancer:
    servers:
      - url: "http://192.168.95.40:9500"
middlewares:
 # plugin rewrite-headers for subpath
 adjust-adguard-redirect:
   plugin:
     traefik-plugin-rewrite-headers:
       rewrites:
         - header: "Location"
           regex: "^/(.*)"
           replacement: "/agh/$1"
 strip-adguard-prefix:
   stripPrefix:
     prefixes:
       - "/agh"
```

This solution allowed me to correctly handle redirects by adding the necessary prefix to the path in the `Location` header, thereby preserving the URL structure when redirecting users.

It would be great to have the ability to make `adh` a `variable` so that one middleware could be applied to different routers.